# Derivation of virial theorem

Tags: virial-theorem

Could you explain the highlighted equality, please? Why is there the second derivative? It is from the derivation of the Virial Theorem. The derivation starts with multiplying 2. Jeans equation with $x_k$. $\bar{v}$ means mean velocity. Thanks

Moment of inertia tensor:

$$I_{jk}=\int \rho x_j x_k \,\mathrm{d}^3 x$$

Chandrasekhar tensor of potential energy:

$$W_{jk}=-\int \rho x_j \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x_k} \,\mathrm{d}^3 x$$
$$\int x_k\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\nu\bar{v}_j) \,\mathrm{d}^3 x+\int x_k\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(\nu\overline{v_i v_j}) \,\mathrm{d}^3 x+\int x_k\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x_i}\nu \, \mathrm d^3 x=0$$

$$\int x_k\frac{\partial }{\partial t}(\rho \bar{v}_j)\,\mathrm d^3x+\int x_k\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}(\rho \overline{v_i v_j})\,\mathrm d^3x+\int x_k \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x_i}\rho\,\mathrm d^3 x=0$$

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\int x_k\rho \bar{v}_j\, \mathrm d^3 x=\frac12\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int\rho(x_k\bar{v}_j+x_j\bar{v}_k)\,\mathrm d^3 x\,\boxed{\color{red}{=}}\,\frac12\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\int\rho x_j x_k\,\mathrm d^3 x=\frac12\frac{d^2}{dt^2}I_{jk}$$

Comment: You haven't explained your notation. I'm not sure about the bar on the $v$, so I might be wrong, but what is $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\left(x_j x_k \right)$?

Comment: I edited my question. I am not sure about $x_jx_k$. Are they position vector from the matrix (tensor)?

Comment: Are you referring to [the Chandrasekhar virial equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrasekhar_virial_equations) ?

Comment: Yes, one of the Chandrasekhar potential energy tensor

Comment: Using inline mathjax is preferred to images of equations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the definition of $\bar{v}$ is, but my guess would be you just have to use the chain rule:
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}(x_ix_j)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(x_ix_j)\right]=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial t}x_j+x_i\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial t}\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\bar{v}_ix_j+x_i\bar{v}_j)$$